# python - numpy array gets imported as str using read_csv()

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am importing a df like

```
dbscan_parameter_search = pd.read_csv('./src/temp/05_dbscan_parameter_search.csv',
                                      index_col=0)

type(dbscan_parameter_search['clusters'][0])
```

which results in `str`.

How can I keep the datatype as numpy array? I tried

```
dbscan_parameter_search = pd.read_csv('./src/temp/05_dbscan_parameter_search.csv',
                                      dtype={'clusters':np.int32},
                                      index_col=0)
```

which results in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[     0      1      2 ... 139634 139634 139636]'`.

Any hint? Thanks

Comment: look at or print the first few lines of the cav.  I think the array elements were saved as strings.

Comment: The string it's trying to convert is the print summary of a large array.  See the '...'?  That's in the file.  It can't be converted back to  the original array.

Comment: You *really* should consider an alternative format. Maybe pickle?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Honestly I don't know it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hpaulj, the problem was rather the export but the import. String was literally saved with dots. For quick workaround see here:
[python - how to to_csv() with an column of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67379614/python-how-to-to-csv-with-an-column-of-arrays#67379827)