# python - how to to_csv() with an column of arrays

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data containing some large arrays in a .csv like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for x in range(1, 6):
    data = {'a':x,
            'b':np.array(range(1, 10000))}

    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(f"./src/temp/test.csv", index=True)
```

The array get saved like:

```
0 1 [   1    2    3 ... 9997 9998 9999]
1 2 [   1    2    3 ... 9997 9998 9999]
2 3 [   1    2    3 ... 9997 9998 9999]
3 4 [   1    2    3 ... 9997 9998 9999]
4 5 [   1    2    3 ... 9997 9998 9999]
```

Which makes it impossilbe to read them later. How can I solve this?

EDIT: I was planning to read it later like:

```
convert = lambda x: np.fromstring(x.strip('[]'), dtype=int, sep=' ')
df = pd.read_csv('./src/temp/test.csv',
                  converters={'b': convert},
                  index_col=0)
```

Comment: Who/what is the intended reader? Pickle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the numpy printing `threshold` with [**`set_printoptions()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html#numpy.set_printoptions):

> `threshold`: Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than full repr (default 1000). To always use the full repr without summarization, pass [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize).

```py
np.set_printoptions(threshold=100000) # or threshold=sys.maxsize
df.to_csv('./src/temp/test.csv', index=True)
```